# CGPDFDocument and local data

Tags: cocoa, url, pdf, core-data, cgpdfdocument

I have some NSData in Core Data db (it's pdf data) and I would like to print my pdf with CGPDFDocument. 
I have to use url of the data but I don't know how to make this with a local data (in my Core Data db).
Someone has an idea ? :)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on macOS, use [-[PDFDocument  initWithData:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzFramework/Classes/PDFDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/PDFDocument/initWithData:).

If you are on iOS, use [CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFDocument/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider) with a [CGDataProviderRef](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGDataProvider/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000952-CH1g-CJBIBEBE).

Also, this is a duplicate of [CGPDFDocumentRef from NSData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875672/cgpdfdocumentref-from-nsdata).